# Unity: Ragdoll colliders&rigidbodies get removed

Tags: unity-game-engine

So my team is developing a game, and we use github&git for version control stuff. But every time when I test the ragdoll character(on player death), only the **bottom** of the ragdoll character does anything. On other team members the ragdoll works just fine, unless I push a commit wiht my faulty character. Please help. Lots of thanks.

EDIT: The problem was solved. We had accidentally git.ignore:d a folder full of important stuff.

I know I have way too little detail in this question to be helpful, but as the problem no longer even exists, I won't update this question in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give very much information with which to answer the question. If you could provide more details, we could provide a more useful answer. For example, the inspector view of the ragdoll or your hierarchy would be helpful.

Some possibilities based on what information you did give:

1. This could be the result of you using a different version of Unity than other developers on your team. Please verify you're using the same version as them.
2. Another developer on your team may have forgotten to push something to git for the ragdoll.
3. You could have some changes made to the character without knowing it. Look for any differences between you and the git main branch and revert them.
4. There are files that didn't fit into the git repo. Those missing files may be causing the problem.

Good luck. I know it's frustrating to deal with problems like this but you will make it through.